# Arduino amplifier

Tags: arduino-uno, voltage-level

I want to drive my model trains (märklin) with my arduino UNO, it requires 32 watt (`0-12/24v, 2A MAX(changes)`)
This is Direct current

How can I amplify the output of the arduino to get my 32 watt?

Comment: Usefully driving trains is more than a matter of on/and off, but involves PWM and possibly more complicated waveforms.  I expect if you look on train enthusiast sites you will find documentation of both manual throttles and automated drivers, probably no few of them based on ATmega MCUs if not the Arduino libraries as well.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can. For relatively small amplifications, you can use transistors. MOSFETs are similar and work well for larger solid state amplification. If all you need is to turn power on or off (no switching faster than ~20Hz) a relay is you best bet, but most standard ones take more power than a raw arduino output can provide so you have to buy one for this purpose. They are all easy to use, for the most part just plug in ground, power, signal, and signal out. You can look up any of these for more details on use, it should not be hard to find.

The easiest pre-built solution is something like this relay board: http://www.sainsmart.com/arduino-compatibles-1/relay/arduino-pro-mini.html

Comment: I would love to be able to either adjust the voltage, live: to control the speed of the train, or be able to use PWM, which will also work with my trains.

Comment: a transistor/MOSFET can switch fast enough to do PWM. The DC motor driver John referenced will also do exactly what you want.

Comment: Definitely go with MOSFETs. Normal transistors will get quite hot when you run 2A through them.

Answer (score 0):

This company, among others, has a range of drivers, meeting your volt/current/PWM speed control requirements, with good documentation, manual and use examples. http://www.pololu.com/category/11/brushed-dc-motor-drivers